# Number of posts needed?

Tags: wood, outdoor, load-bearing, support, retaining-wall

I have no idea what math needs to be done to figure this out, but let me set the stage for you.

I'm building a BIG planter box in my yard. 27ft X 54ft X 5ft high. We want to utilize our whole yard to grow in, and as it stands, we just have way too much standing water/flooding to do it in the ground without raising it up.

I've gone through a few different ideas of the best way to do it, but I've settled on this: I'm using reclaimed 2x4s from pallets to build wooden walls, which I then will screw into posts around the perimeter of the box. Trying to save as much money as possible, since I simply can't afford all the supplies if I were to buy them new.

That bears the question, just how many posts do I need? I was planning on buying 6X6 posts, but using 4X4s would be cheaper if I could get away with it. I know I need at least a post on each corner, and probably some unknown amount of posts in between the corners. Factoring in concrete needed to support the post, each 6X6 post would cost about $70, and each 4X4 would cost about $50. I appreciate help figuring this out, more so if I can see some sources on how to calculate this myself. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're going to be containing 270 cubic yards of dirt in this box. I'm pretty sure you've figured out that one post at each corner isn't going to cut it. What you're really doing is building 4 retaining walls that happen to connect in a rectangle instead of being linear. Think like that and you'll be on the right track. I'm reasonably certain that you're not going to hold all that dirt back with a 2"x4"x54' wooden wall unless you're putting a post every 4-6 feet at a maximum.

Comment: According to [WikiHow](https://www.wikihow.com/How-Much-Does-a-Yard-of-Dirt-Weigh) an _average_ cubic yard of dirt is roughly 2100 pounds and up to 3000 pounds when wet (which yours will be since you're gardening in it). You're looking at 810,000 pounds (405 _tons_) of weight to contain. Don't under sell this. If you're going to splash out the cash for this much dirt, build a proper retaining wall to hold it back.

Comment: Do you really need 5 feet above the ground? Is it possible to dig down a foot or two (to fill with better quality soil than what you have naturally) and up a foot or two? That will make a *huge* difference in how much the walls need to hold back. At 5' you have to *seriously* worry that a collapse (e.g., if marginally built and then a severe rainstorm or 2 feet of melting snow, etc.) could severely injure anyone nearby. With 1 foot - or even probably 2 feet - above ground the risk is far, far, less.

Comment: Unless there is a typo and you forgot the decimals, 2.7 x 5.4, I would go for a bunch of smaller boxes.  Quite a few designs online for raised beds of a comfortable size not to have to walk in them.  At the small size, can build the planter boxes on half pallets with maybe four posts.  Planters are usually a foot or two high at most, unless growing trees.

Comment: Thanks for the service so far! Indeed, no typos, we were genuinely looking at almost 300 yards^3. We did consider multiple boxes, but we really don't want too much wasted space. As far as height, I'm open to different number, but I reasonably need to have at least a foot of sand at the bottom for drainage. Beyond that, I was going to use a mix of wood chips, dirt, and compost to plant in. Would 3 feet really be high enough? Also, how would a proper retaining wall differ? I see several pictures showing some bracing on the outside, is that about it?

Comment: Pallet lumber will rot away in short order, and the whole thing will collapse into a pile of dirt. So if you can't afford to do it right, just put in a pile of dirt and vegetate the edges to build those as steeply as you can hold without any lumber. If you could afford to do it rght, cor-ten sheet pilings and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: That's not a planter box, it's a major land grading exercise, It probably needs planning and building permission (you say you are raising your entire property 5 feet?), which I think and hope you would not get.  It's impractical -- how will you tend a 5-foot high garden?  A ramp would need to be about 50 feet long.  Why does it need to be so high?  You obviously don't have 5 feet of water in your yard.

Comment: Mind clarifying what you mean by vegetating the edges? I was also planing to use hardwood pallets, as well as treating them myself before use. I'll have to look up what corten sheet pilings are.

Comment: Jay, I get about a foot of standing water, enough that ducks start swimming in it in spring lol. We were fully planning to be walking inside the box, and I was going to be making a small set of stairs to get in and out. I'm pretty new to growing things, so I got in my head that 3 or 4 feet of dirt was reasonable to grow in long term. Thus the 5 foot figure.

Comment: If you're going to be doing this much dirt works, consider putting the efforts into improving drainage from your yard instead of building this massive earthworks _on_ it. By improving the drainage of the yard, you'll also be reducing the standing water that's attempting to enter your house and destroy it, and that will save you considerable money and heartache in the long run.

Comment: Suggestion:  Plan differently.  Few things need 3 feet of dirt.  Don't grow those.  Some things grow in pots.  The pots can sit on wood tables you make from pallets.  Most things will grow in a foot of soil.  Look at pictures of a typical public allotment garden.  They are often located in wet/mushy areas. Build several boxes, 4 feet wide and 2 feet high so you can stand or kneel next to them and reach at least half way across.  Put enough gravel/sand at the bottom to get out of the water, and soil above that.  One box can be a little higher to accommodate plants that need more soil.

Comment: Also, if you don't have experience farming, start small.  20 square feet and 6 pots.  Vegetable gardens need a lot of care and TLC.  Each one has its own problems, needs, bugs, diseases, etc.  There is a lot of learning and a lot of work.  Figure out how much you are able to bite off, before biting it all off.

Comment: Vegetating the edges - if you pile dirt, it falls down until it arrives at its "angle of repose" where it's stable. But if rain falls on it it's prone to erode further. If you stabilize the dirt with roots and plants, it can be stable at a steeper angle, and resist erosion. So, using sod or other vegetation at the edges of an earthworks can permit those edges to be steeper than a pile of raw dirt.

Comment: Thanks, Jay. You make some really good points. I think I'll head back to the drawing board, and see about getting much smaller boxes, and maybe see about having rows of them. I'll lose some space, but the alternative issues that have been brought up I think are worth the sacrifice

Comment: Another thing is **pallets**. They are great, cheap (often free if you haul 'em) lumber. But they are (a) not usually given away for free until they are falling apart, which doesn't matter for some uses but certainly matters for something where you are relying on them for structural integrity; (b) they are usually made of the cheapest would available in a given location (i.e., whatever local lumber is cheapest) and at the destination (after a freight delivery, or multiple, possibly across the world) you may find quite a mix of types. Fine for some uses, but not for serious construction.

Comment: Freeman, thankfully water damage to the house isn't a concern. My yard is weird, but essentially the parts that flood are nowhere even close to buildings, thus why it hasn't really been an issue until now. I basically just lose my backyard in spring, but nothing other than that.

Comment: Regarding the pallets, I've been very selective about the ones I use. I've only gathered hardwood pallets in good condition. Thankfully, I have access to many pallets for free through my work!

Comment: Obviously, from the stack of comments above, this question is too broad. Please revise to share a specific design. 4x4 posts are great plenty, and cost is off topic here, so don't bother mentioning it. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of a giant earthworks project, consider making raised beds instead. Raised bed gardening becomes more and more attractive with the passing years because there's less bending and stooping required when you till, cultivate, weed and harvest. It also lets you plant in good soil that you bring in if the local soil is sub-optimal, such as hardpan, sand, rocky soil or too wet as in your case. If you get occasional standing water, you can make a low boardwalk between the raised beds to keep you out of the water and mud.

[Backwoods Home Magazine](https://www.backwoodshome.com/) has run numerous articles on raised bed gardening. (No personal connection except that I'm a subscriber.) Here is [one such article](https://www.backwoodshome.com/three-raised-bed-designs/) that uses pallets to construct the raised beds. Photo by Joe Mooney.

[image: e]

Comment: From all I've read now from the comments, I think this will be the way to go. I was concerned about soil depth at first, but it sounds like my initial plan is just too much to handle.

Comment: @bob152637485  Should use google to find how much area you do need.  It is different from a big family living totally off the land to a family that just wants to grow a few things to have fresh.  Also remember everything you grow and not eat right away, needs storage space somewhere, pantry, freezer/s, shelves for canned goods.  Storing food the right way is almost as hard/important as growing the food.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the actual question: you need as many posts as you need. Your pallet is, what, 4’ long, so your posts are a little less than 4’ apart. Typically, posts with ground contact are made of pressure treated wood, but if it was me, I’d consider rot-resistant untreated alternatives.

Lots of valuable side information in the comments, especially regarding fixing the yard drainage first. The money you spend on drainage will probably be massively offset by the savings in topsoil you don’t have to buy.

Comment: I agree on the useful information in the comments, and all in all, I think it's back to the drawing board to rethink my plans!